# Change scale on a graph

Tags: plotting

I have a graph obtained using ListPlot. What I plot goes between -1000 and +75.

I would like to construct a graph showing the whole range, with a scale such that what is between 0 and 100 takes about the same place as what is between -1000 and 0. To have something like that (for the vertical axis):

[image]

Would you have an idea I could use to avoid doing that "by hand"?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What if you add `PlotRange -> All`?

Comment: "What I plot goes between -1000 and +75" are you referring to the horizontal or vertical scale here? Can you show an example with code and data?

Comment: @J.M.: thanks a lot. I have included a figure to better illustrate what I want to do.

Comment: @MarcoB: thanks a lot. The range I was referring to was the vertical axis. I just added a figure I made to illustrate what I am trying to do. I hope it clarifies it.

Comment: @Laurent I think you might consider a log plot (e.g. ListLogPlot) after rescaling your data so it is no longer negative (e.g. by adding a positive constant to it?). I am also concerned that the readability of your proposed plot would be very poor: the reader's eye would be greatly deceived by your subtle and non-standard change in scale.

Comment: Thanks a lot @MarcoB. This kind of scale variation is quite usual (it is used a lot in the graphs by Thomas Piketty (but not vertically - he does it horizontally).

Comment: Hi, what about making 2 plots with different `PlotRange` settings, the first from 0 to 80 and the second from -1000 to 0. And then stack them vertically?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`ScalingFunctions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ScalingFunctions.html) option

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

SeedRandom[1234];

data = Table[{RandomReal[10], RandomReal[{-1000, 100}]}, {20}];

f = If[# > 0, 10 #, #] &;

ListPlot[data,
 PlotRange -> {-1000, 100},
 Ticks -> {Automatic, 
   Join[Range[0, 100, 20], Range[-1000, -200, 200]]},
 ScalingFunctions -> {None, {f, InverseFunction[f]}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Great! Thank you so much for your help. This is perfect :-)

Comment: I have been trying to understand the code, and tried to make a few changes to it. How could I proceed if I wanted to keep the same scale for values of y = [- 100, 100] and the scale 1/10 for y = [-1000,-100] ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is `f = If[# > -100, #, #/10] &;` what you want?